# What is the meaning of timer precision and resolution?

Tags: c#

I don't understand the meaning of timer precision and resolution. Can anyone explain it to me?

NOTE: This question is related to Stopwatch.

Answer (score 6):

Accuracy and precision are opposing goals, you can't get both.  An example of a very accurate timing source is DateTime.UtcNow.  It provides absolute time that's automatically corrected for clock rate errors by the kernel, using a timing service to periodically re-calibrate the clock.  You probably heard of time.windows.com, the NTP server that most Windows PC use.  Very accurate, you can count on less than a second of error over an entire year.  But not precise, the value only updates 64 times per second.  It is useless to time anything that takes less than a second with any kind of decent precision.

The clock source for Stopwatch is very different.  It uses a free running counter that is driven by a frequency source available somewhere in the chipset.  This used to be a dedicate crystal running at the [color burst frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_burst) (3.579545 MHz) but relentless cost cutting has eliminated that from most PCs.  Stopwatch is very precise, you can tell from its Frequency property.  You should get something between a megahertz and the cpu clock frequency, allowing you to time down to a microsecond or better.  But it is not accurate, it is subject to electronic part tolerances.  Particularly mistrust any Frequency beyond a gigahertz, that's derived from a multiplier which also multiplies the error.  And beware the Heisenberg principle, starting and stopping the Stopwatch takes non-zero overhead that will affect the accuracy of very short measurements.  Another common accuracy problem with Stopwatch is the operating system switching out your thread to allow other code to run.  You need to take multiple samples and use the median value.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same as with any measurement.  See this Wikipedia article for more details --

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of times in .net (3 or 4 of them, if i remember correctly), each working with his own algorithm. The precision of timer means how accurate it is in informing the using application on the ticking events. For example, if you use a timer and set it to trigger its ticking event every 1000 ms, the precision of the timer means how close to the specified 1000 ms it will actually tick.

for more information (at least in c#), i suggest u read [the msdn page on timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx):

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN [Stopwatch Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx): (emphasis mine)

"The Stopwatch measures elapsed time by counting timer ticks in the underlying timer mechanism. If the installed hardware and operating system support a high-resolution performance counter, then the Stopwatch class uses that counter to measure elapsed time. Otherwise, the Stopwatch class uses the system timer to measure elapsed time. **Use the Frequency and IsHighResolution fields to determine the precision and resolution of the Stopwatch** timing implementation."